# Importing and developing WinForms applications on linux

Tags: c#, winforms, mono

I have a Visual Studio C# project, with a GUI done in WinForms. I'd like to continue its development on Linux. I have two questions: firstly, how can I compile it on Linux? I can compile single .cs files that use WinForms, but I have no idea about whole projects. Secondly, how can I further edit the GUI, other than by code? is there some editor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Mono. They have a [guide here](http://www.mono-project.com/Guide%3a_Porting_Winforms_Applications) specifically for porting WinForms apps to Mono.

Answer (score 6):

Have you seen [MonoDevelop](http://monodevelop.com/) ?

> MonoDevelop is an IDE primarily designed for C# and other .NET languages. MonoDevelop enables developers to quickly write desktop and ASP.NET Web applications on Linux, Windows and Mac OSX. MonoDevelop makes it easy for developers to port .NET applications created with Visual Studio to Linux and to maintain a single code base for all platforms.

Answer (score 2):

You should look at the [guide](http://www.mono-project.com/Guide%3a_Porting_Winforms_Applications) Mono people have prepared thinking of you. 
Nevertheless, if you have special questions (like video) on your WinForms application, be ready to learn more than a bit of Gtk#.

Immediate future development from Mono people will pave the way for these applications to be ported with a bit more comfort, but that's in the future.

Good luck, anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Look for Mono Project at http://www.mono-project.com/Main_Page. it is a cross platform implementation of .net framework and has editor to edit winforms.

Answer (score 0):

You can continue to use Visual Studio. No need to specifically compile for Linux (except for some well [documented](http://www.mono-project.com/Guidelines%3aApplication_Portability) caveats). Just copy your .exe file over, and run it using Mono.

You will soon find out if winforms works well or not. It depends which controls your using.